# Gambler's ruin - Why is the probability of never reaching the barriers 0?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk, gambling

I have found online this [pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-GRP.pdf) which treats the gambler's ruin problem. However, in the first page the writer implicitly assumes that the gambler must reach one of the barriers (state $0$ or $N$) in finite time. It seems that it uses this implicit assumption to justify that the probability of ruin is $1-P_i(N)$. Is there a way to justify it without using that assumption? I think it has to do with that the probability of never reaching a barrier is $0$, but how can I prove it?

Comment: I think you mean state $0$ or state $N$ (with only two states $0,1$, this is trivial). Anyway, if you know Markov chain theory, this is easy to prove; look into "first hitting time and chance analysis". Briefly, let $h_k$ be the probability of ever hitting $0$ or $1$ (whichever happens first) starting from state $k$ $(0\leq k \leq N)$. We have the boundary conditions $h_0=1=h_1$, (why?). Next, by conditional probability, we obtain the following recurrence $h_{k} = ph_{k+1}+qh_{k-1}$ (why?). Once you solve this (how?), we obtain $h_k=1$ for all $0\leq k\leq N$, thus we are sure to be absorbed.

Comment: The steps are independent and have finite variance.  Apply the central limit theorem.

Comment: @NapD.Lover's comment provides a sketch of a proof, though I assume they meant to write $h_0 = 1 = h_N$ rather than $h_0 = 1 = h_1$.

Comment: @BrianTung Indeed, thank you for catching that! Still need more coffee today, it seems...

Comment: Incidentally, because it can be a conceptual hurdle, it should be pointed out that just because an event has probability zero, does not mean that it categorically cannot happen. This is a weird thing (weird, at least, to students of probability) that happens with infinite sets of outcomes.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Thank you, of course, I edited my question

Comment: @NapD.Lover Is there an easy way to infer that $h_k = 1$ for all $k$?

Comment: @Algo Yes--but this method is applicable in general, so it is nice to be aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if there were ever to be a sequence of $N$ winning bets in a row, the game must have ended at some point in that sequence (even if the gambler started at \$1, they would have ended up at \$N.  If they started below \$1, the game ended at some earlier point).  We can show the probability of ever getting a streak of $N$ wins is $1$.

Let $A_0$ be the event that we get a streak of $N$ heads starting from the $0$-th toss, $A_1$ be the event that we get a streak of $N$ heads starting from the $N+1$-st toss, and so on to define $A_n$.  Note that $P(A_n) = p^N > 0$, and each $A_n$ is independent.  The probability of getting a streak of $N$ heads is at least
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = 1-\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c) = 1-\prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_n^c) = 1-\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q)^N = 1,
\end{align*}
so we conclude that the probability that the gambler's wealth hits a barrier at some point is $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Excellent explaination!

Answer (score -1):

The game can only end in one of two ways - the gambler reaches their target, or goes broke. There is no other option besides win or lose - to say there is a non-zero probability of not reaching either barrier is to say that there is some fraction of games that end without winning or losing, but that defies the very premise of the game. "The game isn't over yet" is not a valid outcome of the game, the game is defined such that you *must continue playing* until you hit one of the barriers.

Comment: You claim without giving a reason that  (for example) that the sequence of states alternating $2,3,2,3,2,3,\dots$ indefinitely has probability zero.

Comment: I also tried the chain of thought that you have here, but that simply doesn't work in the limiting case as $N\to \infty$, where the number of state is infinite and that corresponds for a player playing against an infinitely rich casino. Then, as it stems from the PDF I provided, it is possible, with nonzero probability, for the game to never end and for the player to get infinitely rich.